# Change CSS on Text When An Image is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have an image that acts as a button and text lower on the page. How would I set it up with javascript and css so that when you click on the image the text color would change below?

```
<input type="image" id="theButton" src="https://cdn0.vox-
cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" 
style="height:50px" />

 <p>
text 1
</p>

<p>
text2
</p>
```

Comment: Please always include code when asking questions. Or else no one will answer you and you will be downvoted.

Comment: What is the question? Please read through [ask]

Comment: Sorry. I didn't finish and his the comment button accidentally. All set.

Comment: What about clicking it again? you want it to change back color?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

Attach a 'click' event to the button using `addEventListener('click')`. Then style accordingly.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/qmpf7702/)

**HTML**

```
    <input type="image" src="https://cdn0.vox-
cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" id="theButton" style="height: 50px;"/>

<p>Text 1</p>

<p>Text 2</p>
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector('p').style.color='green';
})
```

Comment: That doesn't work. You are only changing one paragraph color.

Comment: I assumed the second <p> was there to see the contrast between the color change. Not change both.

Comment: Also it doesn't toggle. So stop downvoting my answer just cuz your browser doesn't run javascript or something when your answer is inferior

Comment: Oh i'm sorry then i'm actually a brash monster on here sometimes :(

Comment: And yet again... this is why I don't like downvoting.

Comment: Yea i'm sorry man you didn't do anything wrong, I was the one making assumptions. I need to take a chillpill and stop acting like is facebook

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to use jQuery toggleClass.

jQuery

```
$("elementToBeClicked").on('click',function() { 
          $("elemenToBeAltered").toggleClass('classThatDefinesNewProperties');
        });
```

and css:

```
.classThatDefinesNewProperties {
  color:red; /* example change color to red*/
}
```

Fore more info visit: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp

Answer (score -1):

This one's on me: (fresh with es6 stuff)

```js
let theButton = document.getElementById('theButton');
let theText = document.querySelectorAll('.the-text');

theButton.onclick = function () { 
  for(let x of theText) {
    x.classList.toggle('colorized');
  }
};
```

```css
.the-text {
  color: blue;
}

.the-text.colorized {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="image" id="theButton" src="https://cdn0.vox-
cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/4039958/ama-orange.0.png" 
style="height:50px" />
  
<p class="the-text">Hey look at me changing color on that image click!</p>
<p class="the-text">Hey more text</p>
```

Comment: I'm sorry you're experiencing browser issues. Try copying the code and then tell me it doesn't work.

Comment: I put it in a fiddle and it works fine. It's not the browser. I just don't like these snippets. They're not always reliable.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thank you.